# how to run the program and pass arguments to the program using bash file on linux

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments, root, raspbian

I want to run the program ***example.cpp*** and pass arguments ***./example -a 25 -f park.mp4*** through bash file. I am not sure whether it is possible or not. If it is possible, please help me with the steps.

Comment: You can't normally run a `.cpp` file, you need to compile it first.

Comment: Are needing to compile the .cpp file or are you just looking to change the permissions.

Comment: its possible. Just first compile the cpp then a object will be created,then do the execution

Comment: So here are the steps..

Comment: 1) First I will compile the example.cpp file normally.                                                                                                                        2) Create the bash file and include the arguments ./example -a 25 -f park.mp4 in it.                                                                                                    3)do the execution.

Comment: @Kishan Kumar Please let me know if i am following wrong steps above. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linux

save this in a .sh file

```
/path/to/executable arg1 arg2
```

Then run

```
./file.sh
```

with proper permission

Comment: what is executable? .cpp file or ./a.out file? thats where i am getting confuse.

Comment: Yeah it worked. I have improved your answer by adding few more steps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to pass arguments to the script that in turn will pass the arguments to the program. So that is what my answer is geared towards.

First you need compile the .cpp file if you don't supply a name it will be a.out. Then to pass arguments to it you can follow some of the examples I found in this post. 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32290/pass-command-line-arguments-to-bash-script

Another good place to look is the bash home page that will have detailed examples you can use to build the script you want, and also use some of the information for later solutions.

Another good site to use.
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: I'm sorry I should say bash scripting since there are so many sites that have good information and examples for bash scripting.